# HTTP only cookie in express doesnt set

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I have app.ts file:

```
import express, { Express } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
//
import userRouter from "./routes/userRoutes";
import cardsRouter from "./routes/cardsRoutes";
import contactsRouter from "./routes/contactsRoutes";
import transferRouter from "./routes/transferRoutes";
import authRouter from "./routes/authRoutes";
//
const app: Express = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:4200",
  })
);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(202)
    .cookie("Name", "testCookie", {
      sameSite: "strict",
      path: "/",
      expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 100 * 1000),
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
    })
    .send("success!");
});
app.use("/api/v1", [
  userRouter,
  cardsRouter,
  contactsRouter,
  transferRouter,
  authRouter,
]);

export default app;
```

and service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
  url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login';
  token: string = '';

  async login(formObject: any) {
    try {
      await axios
        .get(`${this.url}`, { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => console.log(res));

      console.log('http cookie set!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

login route leads to this controller:

```
export const checkCookie = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello" });
};
```

when i click login theres no error, but i get no cookie either. I check it in mozilla devtools -> storage -> cookies, and there are test cookies, but no http only cookie. What is wrong? The server runs of 8000 port and frontend od 4200.